# cy.wrap(JQueryObject).click() vs JQueryObject.click()

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, typescript2.0

Hi can anyone explain to me a little bit why I can not just use `element.click()` on line `cy.wrap(element).click()`? what is the benefit to use cy.wrap for it?

```
  cy.get(selector)
    .scrollIntoView()
    .each((element) => {
      if (element.text() === 'click me') {
        cy.wrap(element).click();
      }
    });
```

Comment: `element` in this case is a `jQuery` object (or maybe a collection of of objects) and I think calling just `element.click()` will probably work as well. However, with `cy.wrap(element).click()` Cypress will check that the element is visible and is not covered by other elements so it wouldn't be possible to interact with it by users. Then also that the element is not detached from DOM and so on.

Comment: so which way is preferred for writing cypress test?

Comment: I would definitely go with `cy.wrap(element).click()`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is because it will show up nice in the cypress logs and you will gain confidence about the *user* interactions with that element (as opposed to machine interaction).

I guess that in this specific case you can view it as the difference between invoking the `onclick` handler manually and having a bot click a virtual mouse on the interactable element, the latter being much closer to the human interaction, resulting in more confidence.

You might find this cumbersome, but 90% of cases you won't even need to use `cy.wrap` because you can reach the wrapped element directly.

This snippet should do the job I reckon, I would also skip `scrollIntoView()`. If this is this only element with "click me" on the page, I would supply just the text, without a selector.

```js
cy.contains(selector, 'click me')
  .scrollIntoView()
  .click()
```